# MySQLWorkbench How to create Date only column to be updated every time I ingest new data

Tags: date, sql-update, mysql-workbench

I already have a date time column which is updated every time I ingest new data and it works, but I would like to do the same for a new column but just with the date, not the time. Please see the picture attached. What should I write in the Default option? [Table column definitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciNIi.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could set the default value to `CURRENT_DATE ON UPDATE CURRENT_DATE` in your `EventDate` field.

But wouldn't it be better to extract date from the already existing `EventDateTime` field with `DATE_FORMAT(EventDateTime, '%Y-%m-%d')` or `DATE(EventDateTime)` functions?

Comment: Many thanks mate, but could I use those functions in the default script from the Date Column? Actually if I write CURRENT_DATE ON UPDATE CURRENT_DATE I do get an error

Comment: What is the default value of `EventDateTime`? Try to copy and change `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to `CURRENT_DATE` or to `CURDATE` everywhere. I don't think you can use `date` and `date_format` there, but maybe you just don't need to.

Comment: Yes I agree. But how do I create a column with a default function of DATE(EventDateTime) or DATE_FORMAT(EventDateTime, '%Y-%m-%d') as you suggested?

Comment: I suggested not to use in the default value of `EventDate` but every time you need a date you simply call this function on your `EventDateTime` field as it already contains all the necessary information about date. But in some cases it is more preferable to use another field with separate date. It is called [functional dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_dependency).

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't that be manual? I.E every time I would write a sql statement I would use a date function of my choice? That's what I wanted to avoid, I wanted the data to be there automatically in YYYY-MM-DD format every time I simply write select * from Table

Comment: So what's the default value for `EventDateTime`? Could you paste it here?